# How to make flutter app font size independent from accesibility settings

Tags: flutter, webview, settings, font-size

I'm trying to develop flutter app using webview. The problem is that when I modify accessibility settings i.e. increase font size. My app webview becomes all messed up. I tried to implement MediaQuery approcah:

```
return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          child: child!,
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
        );
      },
      title: 'App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
          title: 'Home Page',
    );
```

But it did not help. I'm guessing it is because I'm using webview. any ideas how to disable accessibility settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach works for the application interface. For webview, you should define "webSettings.setTextZoom(100)" in the controller.

To make this setting, you can look at the platform specific section; https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter#platform-specific-features

The relevant update is here: https://github.com/flutter/packages/pull/3298